# mySQL SELECT two or more rows in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the below code to query an pull Category and Stock of the first 30 Product ID that are store into the $IDs array in PHP.

```
//Category
for ($n = 0; $n < 30; $n++) {
    $ID = $IDs[$n];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Category FROM Products where Code= '$ID'", $link);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $productCategory[$n] = $row["Category"];
    }
}
//Stock
for ($n = 0; $n < 30; $n++) {
    $ID = $IDs[$n];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Stock FROM Products where Code= '$ID'", $link);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $productStock[$n] = $row["Stock"];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to query and pull both Category and Stock with the same SELECT  so i can minimise the queries to mySQL DB to only 30 not 60?

Comment: So not use `mysql_*` functions. These api is depricated. Use `mysqli_*` functions or pdo and prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT Stock, Category FROM Products WHERE Code= '$ID'`

Please note that the `mysql_*` methods have been deprecated in PHP due to their vulnerability to SQL injection. You should use either PDO or mysqli functions.

Comment: Thanks, i know is deprecated but i dont know how to convert it to PDO, i will start learn .. Thanks again for the answer btw